# What is the best open source help ticket system?

Tags: open-source, ticket-system

I know of osTicket, are there any other more compelling help ticket systems?
My company wants to use one and I am researching them now.

I forgot to mention, I will need to install it on our servers...so SaaS (software as a service) doesn't work.

Comment: This depends strongly on your needs, there is no simple answer.

Comment: Right now, my company uses Rational ClearQuest as ticket system...and wants to move on from this expensive choice. By the way, the company is pretty big with thousands of employees.

Comment: I guess this is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114007/free-supportticket-software).

Answer (score 9):

There is good information on Wikipedia at

> [Comparison of Issue Tracking Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems)

Personally, I'm fond of **Trac**, which has the capability of integrating with subversion, so when you check in a file, if you say something like...

```
$ svn ci -m "automatically fix any broken dates in the input.  fixes #87"
```

....then Trac will automatically add this comment and close bug #87 for you.

Comment: Yeah, this seem to be a pretty compelling list...thanks.

Comment: -1: The question was asking about customer support ticket tracking, not source code management.

Comment: @Mark: You're right.  I must've just been eager to vote for Trac.

Comment: It will be used internally, among departments (not externally in relationship with other clients).

Comment: The questioner asked for a Help ticket system, not a bug tracking solution.

Comment: There's a nice list here http://helpdeskreviews.com/open-source-helpdesks.php

Answer (score 8):

"Best" helpdesk system is very subjective, of course, but I recommend [Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) (aka RT).

It has a default workflow built in, but is easily configured for alternate workflows using the "Scrips" and templates.  Very extensible if you want.

Comment: +1, I've used this for a help desk. It offers transparency for the customers and if you have a staff willing to use the web interface to close the tickets, it works very well. I'm not very fond of Perl, but it works.

Comment: My company used this RT...it abandoned for Rational Clearquest.

Comment: What didn't your company like about RT?

Answer (score 6):

OTRS, Cerberus

Answer (score 3):

I like [eTicket Support](http://www.eticketsupport.com/), is very simple to use and install.

Answer (score 3):

It absolutely depens on what your goals are. The Bugzilla and Trac systems mentioned are nice but geared towards bug tracking, which is just very different from a tool you'd want to use in a helpdesk-type setup where end users would raise incidents.

If the latter is what you are looking for I'd suggest you take a look at **[OTRS](http://otrs.org)** which is a very capable trouble ticketing system. It also has ITSM extensions, which makes it able to support ITIL processes if you need to.

Comment: +1 Exactly right. Depends on what the goals are. I can recommend OTRS for end user helpdesk!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend OTRS, its very easily customizable, and we also use it for hundreds of employees (University).

Answer (score 1):

Howabout Bugzilla. Open source and what Mozilla uses.

Comment: bug tracking software != help desk system.

Comment: Yes, I want a general help desk system, not a software bug tracking system...

Comment: Just because it has "bug" in the name it doesn't mean you can use it to track help desk issues.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this should be ashamed.  Shame on you.

Comment: joel, joelonsoftware.com. has a number of blogs on using his bug tracker to manage help desk....and more.

Comment: The questioner asked for a Help ticket system, not a bug tracking solution.

Comment: bug tracking is functionally equivalent to ticket tracking

Comment: @warren No it is not.  Ticket tracking is essentially a public help desk.  Bug tracking is internal bug tracking, not meant to be used for the public.

Comment: @leetNightshade - *conceptually*, they **are** identical. Whether it's public or internal is irrelevant: it's the same concept :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple that look pretty decent:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/smallhd/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/helpdeskcsharp/

Comment: SmallHD is no longer under active development (as of 2005!)

Comment: Still looks pretty good though :)

Answer (score 0):

TRAC.  Open source, Python-based

Comment: It seems more oriented to software help desk system...I want a general one (which can be used for general things, not just software).